# Creating a custom array within an array sort function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

What would i need to put in the `SortIP` function to make the custom sort function sort the array by the last digit of the IP number. This doesn't work.

```
function SortIP(a, b)
{
    return a[0][3] - b[0][3];
}

LAN = new Array
(
    ["ADSL Router", [192, 168, 0, 1]],
    ["Gary's Mac", [192, 168, 0, 15]],
    ["Network Switch", [192, 168, 0, 2]],
    ["Production Email", [192, 168, 0, 60]]
);
LAN.sort(SortIP);
```

expected array order:

1. ADSL Router: 192.168.0.1
2. Network Switch: 192.168.0.2
3. Gary's Mac: 192.168.0.15
4. Production Email: 192.168.0.60

Comment: You should use the array literal syntax `[ … ]` and not `new Array()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there

just replace

`return a[0][3] - b[0][3];`

with

`return a[1][3] - b[1][3];`

and you're done.

Why?
Because the IP is the second (Index=1) cell of each array.

Comment: Talk about 'can't see the wood for the trees'! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You’re comparing the wrong values. Try this:

```
function SortIP(a, b) {
    return a[1][3] - b[1][3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The values sent to the sort handler are values of the array being sorted.

Since this is a bubble sort, you have to return 0 if the items are the same, 1 if a > b, and -1 if b > a;

```
function SortIP(a, b)
{
    if ( a[1][3] == b[1][3] ) return 0;
    return ( a[1][3] > b[1][3] ) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: @Peter: return a[1][3] - b[1][3] will return 0 if they are the same. There is a potential for overflow when using 'a - b', but since he is sorting the last value of an IP address, we know that the value will never result in an overflow.

Comment: Yeah, I sorta figured it out after I posted.  I'll leave this as it is, though, as an explicit method for doing the sort.

Answer (score 1):

change your sort function to:

```
function SortIP(a, b)
{
    return a[1][3] - b[1][3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by the complete address, it might be a good idea to write a thin wrapper for the array containing the bytes:

```
function IP4() {
    var ip = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, 4);
    ip.toString = IP4.toString;
    ip.valueOf = IP4.valueOf;
    return ip;
}

IP4.toString = function() {
    return this.join('.');
};

IP4.valueOf = function() {
    return (this[0] << 24) | (this[1] << 16) | (this[2] << 8) | this[3];
};

var LAN = [
    ["ADSL Router", IP4(192, 168, 0, 1)],
    ["Gary's Mac", IP4(192, 168, 0, 15)],
    ["Network Switch", IP4(192, 168, 0, 2)],
    ["Production Email", IP4(192, 168, 0, 60)]
];

LAN.sort(function(a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });
```